# dev86 compile error

Tags: compiler-errors

I have tried to compile dev86 on 2 different machines, one 64bit only and the other a generic 32bit machine.  Both fail at exactly the same spot:

```
make[4]: Entering directory `/tmp/dev86-0.16.17/libc/bcc'
make[4]: *** No rule to make target `__ldivmod.o)', needed by `/tmp/dev86-0.16.17/libc/libc.a'. Stop.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/tmp/dev86-0.16.17/libc/bcc'
make[3]: *** [/tmp/dev86-0.16.17/libc/libc.a] Error 1
```

I have applied the noelks patch to both installs and after typing in make and the screen displays:

```
Select config option to flip [or quit] >
```

I type quit at which point the make continues until my error above. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong and or missing?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you use GNU Make 3.82, not an older one? They seem to broke a processing of automatic variables for archive implicit rules in this version. I see only solution available now -- go back to the version 3.81.